# ¿traer datos de un jtable a unos textfield?

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans-8.2

mi inconveniente es el siguiente, tengo un jtable que cargue con datos de una bd sqlite, cuando presiono un dato del jtable la info del dato se va a unos textfield, como muestra la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hasta hay todo bien si presiono otro igualmente me trae los datos, el problema es que si filtro algún estudiante y lo presiono para que me traiga los datos me trae los de otro, como muestra la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en si es como si cogiera el usuario que filtre y dijera que es el primero entonces me trae los datos del primero y asi con el de abajo si le presiono al otro me trae los datos del 2 usuario no de el 4 que deeria ser..
mi codigo es este:
asi filtro

```
private void txtFiltroKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
    
    txtFiltro.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
            trs.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)"+txtFiltro.getText(),3,13));
        }
         
 });
    trs = new TableRowSorter(modelo);
    tblEstudiantes.setRowSorter(trs);
```

este es e del jtable:

```
  private void tblEstudiantesMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
    if(evt.getClickCount()==1){
      JTable receptor=(JTable)evt.getSource();
      txtID.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),0).toString());
      txtNombre.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),1).toString());
      txtFechaNacimiento.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),2).toString());
      txtIdentificacion.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),3).toString());
      txtEdad.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),4).toString());
      txtSemestre.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),5).toString());
      txtContactoDeEmergencia.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),6).toString());
      txtContactoDeEmergencias.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),7).toString());
      txaConsulta.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),8).toString());
      txaAntecedentes1.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),9).toString());
      txtRemision1.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),10).toString());
      txtRemision2.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),11).toString());
      txaRemision3.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),12).toString());
      txtNombrePsicologa1.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),13).toString());
      txtValidacion.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),14).toString());
      txtFechaActual.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),15).toString());
      txtCorreoEstudiante.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),16).toString());
      txtCelular.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),17).toString());
      txtParentesco.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),18).toString());
      txtArea.setText(receptor.getModel().getValueAt(receptor.getSelectedRow(),19).toString());
    }
```

este es el de la bd al jtable

```
public void MostrarDatos(){
    conexion objConexion=new conexion();
    while(modelo.getRowCount()>0){
        modelo.removeRow(0);
    }
        try {
        ResultSet resultado=objConexion.consultarRegistros("SELECT * FROM Estudiantes");
        while (resultado.next()) {
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("ID"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("Nombre"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("FechaNacimiento"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("Identificacion"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("Edad"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("Semestre"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("ContactoEmNombre"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("ContactoEmNumero"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("MotivoConsulta"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("AntecedentesPersonales"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("RemisionS"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("RemisionN"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("RemisionL"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("NombrePsicologa"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("Validacion"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("FechaActual"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("CorreoEstudiante"));  
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("Celular"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("Parentesco"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("Area"));

            Object[] oUsuario={resultado.getString("ID"),resultado.getString("Nombre"),resultado.getString("FechaNacimiento"),resultado.getString("Identificacion"),resultado.getString("Edad"),resultado.getString("Semestre"),resultado.getString("ContactoEmNombre"),resultado.getString("ContactoEmNumero"),resultado.getString("MotivoConsulta"),resultado.getString("AntecedentesPersonales"),resultado.getString("RemisionS"),resultado.getString("RemisionN"),resultado.getString("RemisionL"),resultado.getString("NombrePsicologa"),resultado.getString("Validacion"),resultado.getString("FechaActual"), resultado.getString("CorreoEstudiante"), resultado.getString("Celular"), resultado.getString("Parentesco"), resultado.getString("Area")};
            modelo.addRow(oUsuario);
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

y eso es lo que tengo, por favor ayuda